# How can I don't trigger $stateChangeStart in angular?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

If I write like this:

```
 $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if ($scope.isChanged) {
        myShowOkCancelDialog(NotifyType.Warn, 'do you want leave?', function (ok) {
            if (ok) {
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            }
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

it will be always asking ok or cancel, and i don't want to use `$window.confirm`:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if ($scope.isChanged) {
        var isjump = confirm('do you want leave?');
        if (!isjump) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not verifiable, please provide a fiddle or a plunker containing the specific services you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to reset `$scope.isChanged` if user wants to leave. Then when you call `$state.go()` the conditional won't cause the warning to show up

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if ($scope.isChanged) {
        myShowOkCancelDialog(NotifyType.Warn, 'do you want leave?', function (ok) {
            if (ok) {
                $scope.isChanged = false;
                // $stateChangeStart will not enter `if` now
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            }
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```